# How to include unequivocal information in Exception in Ruby-optparse?

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-line-arguments

In defining an option-handling in [optparse](https://github.com/ruby/optparse) in Ruby, I would like to raise an exception (`OptionParser::ParseError`) if a certain condition is met, and then would like to *rescue* the exception so as to exit gracefully with a custom message, instead of letting Ruby abort with Exception.

I managed to do it, using `error.message` of an Exception object (sample code attached below, where an exception is raised if the given argument is an odd number).  However, I cannot retrieve essential information like what argument was given.

Moreover, because the algorithm relies on a text message (String) contained in an Exception object, the detection of the exact error cannot be perfect by definition.  Any other Exception objects that happen to be raised may contain a similar String. That's not ideal.

How can I raise a target `OptionParser::ParseError` that has unequivocal information about the error and retrieve the information later?

```rb
# my_prog.rb 
require 'optparse'
opts = OptionParser.new() do |opt|
  optnum = nil
  opt.on("-n", "--num NUM", Integer, "must be even") do |v|
    raise OptionParser::InvalidArgument, "Odd number" if v.odd?
    optnum = v
  end

  begin
    opt.parse!(ARGV)
  rescue OptionParser::InvalidArgument => err
    if err.message.include? "Odd number"
      # err.message => "invalid argument: -n Odd number"
      warn "--num must be even."
      exit 1
    end
    raise
  end
end
p opts
```

Running `my_prog.rb -n 5` catches the exception (in this particular case), but I cannot retrieve the user-given option "5", for example.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is perhaps to define a custom Exception object as a child class of `OptionParser::ParseError`

Then, you have a total control of how and when to raise the Exception. Then, when you rescue it, it is unequivocal.

An `OptionParser::ParseError` object has a constant `Reason` and two attributes `args` and `additional`. `Reason` says what kind of error it is. `args` is an Array of up to 2 elements, where the first element is the given main option and second is the argument if there is any given. `additional` is an extra (I don't think it is documented and may be used only internally, and so there is a risk the specification might change in the future?)

Here is sample code.  Since `OptionParser` allows three forms of how to specify the optional arguments (short, long with a space, and long with `=`), `err.args` has multiple patterns accordingly.

```rb
# my_prog2.rb
require 'optparse'
class NonEvenNumberOption < OptionParser::ParseError
  const_set(:Reason, 'number must be even')
end

opts = OptionParser.new() do |opt|
  opt.on("-n", "--num NUM", Integer, "must be even") do |v|
    raise NonEvenNumberOption, v if v.odd?
    ### Alternatively,
    # raise NonEvenNumberOption.new(v, additional: "extra info") if v.odd?
    ### which is accessible with  err.additional 
  end

  begin
    opt.parse!(ARGV)
  rescue NonEvenNumberOption => err
    # err.args is one of ["-n", 5], ["--num", 5], ["--num=5"]
    warn "ERROR: "+err.reason+": "+err.args.join(" ")
    exit 1
  end
end
```

Then, `my_prog2.rb -n 5` outputs
`ERROR: number must be even: -n 5`

I have posted a fairly extensive Gist of [Ruby-optparse sample code](https://gist.github.com/masasakano/45ee0d737f2d33122e8ff44007693b40), which includes the above-described point.